# How to enable touch mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, progress-bar

I have an sample with images slideshow. In here i am not able to use touch to swipe images from one to another only with the help of button i can change

> Sample - https://codepen.io/Kumaresan_sd/pen/MMVZMj

But in below sample i havent done anything different but touch working fine

can anyone explain why?

> Sample - [CLICK HERE](https://codepen.io/Kumaresan_sd/pen/VJMpaJ)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var time = 2;
  var $bar,
    $slick,
    isPause,
    tick,
    percentTime;

  $slick = $('.slider');
  $slick.slick({
    arrows: true,
    speed: 1200,
    adaptiveHeight: false
  });

  $bar = $('.slider-progress .progress');

  function startProgressbar() {
    resetProgressbar();
    percentTime = 0;
    isPause = false;
    tick = setInterval(interval, 30);
  }

  function interval() {
    if (isPause === false) {
      percentTime += 1 / (time + 0.1);
      $bar.css({
        width: percentTime + "%"
      });
      if (percentTime >= 100) {
        $slick.slick('slickNext');
        startProgressbar();
      }
    }
  }

  function resetProgressbar() {
    $bar.css({
      width: 0 + '%'
    });
    clearTimeout(tick);
  }

  startProgressbar();

  $('.slick-next, .slick-prev').click(function() {
    startProgressbar();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Slider */

.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-list,
.slick-track,
.slick-slide,
.slick-slide img {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-slide>.slick-slider-img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide .image {
  /*height: 180px;*/
}

.slick-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-slide img.slick-loading {
  display: none;
}

.slick-prev {
  background: #DDD;
  border: none;
  border-radius: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 400;
}

.slick-next {
  background: #DDD;
  border: none;
  border-radius: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  right: 0;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  z-index: 400;
}


/* progress bar */

.slider-progress {
  width: 520px;
  height: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  /*   position: absolute; */
  bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 16px
}

.slider-progress .progress {
  width: 0%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #e74c3c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<!-- START SLICK SLIDER -->
<div class="slider-wrapper">
  <div class="slider responsive lazy">
    <div>
      <div class="image"><img class="slick-slider-img" alt="Alt" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464082354059-27db6ce50048?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1271&h=847&q=80" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image"><img class="slick-slider-img" alt="Alt" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1445023835378-9fa9a2089f0c?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1271&h=953&q=80" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image"><img class="slick-slider-img" alt="Alt" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1441040744088-a70b8213d4d4?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1271&h=847&q=80" /></div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="image"><img class="slick-slider-img" alt="Alt" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463608666382-cbb244a7bea2?format=auto&auto=compress&dpr=1&crop=entropy&fit=crop&w=1271&h=1769&q=80" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- END SLICK SLIDER -->

<div class="slider-progress">
  <div class="progress"></div>
</div>
```